# Elastic Enterprise Search: Search API doesnt match “33” for “033” in document title

Tags: elasticsearch

I couldn't figure it out how I can match the title e.g.: "Test title No.033" with query "33".
When I search for "033", it return the document. But for only "33" it doesnt return :frowning:

The guide is not very helpful for me (Search API | Elastic App Search Documentation [7.12] | Elastic)

Could you please help me with this?

What other information should I provide?

Answer (score 1):

If no analyzer is specified then elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).
The tokens generated will be `"test"`, `"title"`, `"no"`, `"033"`

You can use [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to do a partial match on `"title"` field

---

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 5,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze API**

```
GET /_analzye
{
  "analyzer" : "my_analyzer",
  "text" : "Test title No.033"
}
```

The tokens generated will contain both `"033"` and `"33"`

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"Test title No.033"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "title":"33"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67091386",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Test title No.033"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Can I modify analyzer in Elastic Search App?

Comment: @Reechee I am not sure about elastic app search, but you can refer to this blog https://joecwu.medium.com/elastic-app-search-360f0eba04bf

Answer (score 0):

Elastic App Search doesn't allow you to configure the tokenizer like in Elasticsearch. However, you can tune in the results using the [relevance tuning API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/relevance-tuning-guide.html).

You can give more weight to your title, and it will start showing when you search for either "33" or "033".

Note: Relevance tuning has multiple components like Weights, Functions that you could apply. I'd recommend you try it out in the Elastic App Search Console.